# Why isn't this docstring displaying?

Tags: python

Just getting started with "Dive Into Python".  For some reason I can't get a docstring to display.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def buildConnectionString(params):
    """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters
    """
    # Returns string
    return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams = {"server":   "mpilgrim", \
                "database": "master",   \
                "uid":      "sa",       \
                "pwd":      "secret"    \
                }
    print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

At the console:

```
>>> import odbchelper
>>> print odbchelper.buildConnectionString.__doc__
None
>>>
```

This works fine:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.__doc__
"list() -> new empty list\nlist(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items"
>>>
```

I tried a number of permuations, including `"""` and `#` comments.  No joy.  Where is the problem?

Comment: What's wrong with `print buildConnectionString.__doc__`?

Comment: How did you invoke your interpreter at the console?

Comment: (1) It looks like you're using tab indentation (4-space is generally better.)  Could you check your code by running `python -tt odbchelper.py`?  (2) What does `import inspect` and then `print inspect.getsource(odbchelper.buildConnectionString)` show?

Comment: Also, this may seem really stupid, but make sure you're editing the same file you're importing. I can't tell you how many times I've edited `~/src/test/odbcstuff/odbchelper.py` and then started Python in `~/src/test/odbc2` and wondered why `import odbchelper` didn't do the right thing—even after I made sure I did a `^Xs` and `rm *.pyc` and everything else I could think of…

Comment: @Keith I've been using PythonWin, IDLE or simply PowerShell for now.  I haven't tried it on Linux or OSX yet.

Comment: @DSM `import inspect` very cool. I know I'll use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have should work; some possible reasons why it is not:

- You are editing a different file
- You haven't exited and restarted the interpreter after editing the correct file

Update:

If you use `reload` to avoid exiting and restarting the interpreter (or IDLE or whatever you are using) you need to be aware of a couple pitfalls:

- `reload` is not recursive

In other words, if your `odbchelper` imports `odbcstuff` and you `reload(odbchelper)`, `odbcstuff` will not be reloaded.

- `reload` does not update other existing objects

If you try to get around the non-recursive nature of `reload` with

```
import odbcstuff
reload(odbcstuff)
```

the `odbcstuff` that `odbchelper` sees is still the old one;  you need one more step:

```
odbchelper.odbcstuff = odbcstuff     # update odbchelper with the reloaded odbcstuff
```

As you can see, that would be quite tedious for more than a couple dependent modules.  So go ahead and use `reload`, but if things are still not working correctly, exit and restart.

Comment: I think I figure it out based on your answer.  After editing I'd save and `import odbchelper` instead I had to `reload(odbchelper)`